# change the page limit in magento

Tags: backend

i am using Magento 2  , in my case i want to change the default value for the page limit in  section Product in Category, the default value for me is "20 per page" so i want to change it to 100 per page

**PS** : i want to do it programmatically

**PS** : the value 100 is already existed in the options i want just to make it the default value instead of 30

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a module.
- Add a preference for class \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product in etc/adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"
                type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
```

- Set 100 as setDefaultLimit in _construct() function.

```
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
....
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setDefaultLimit(100);
    }
}
```

HTH, Tom

Comment: thank you for your reply , can you please explain this ==> Set 100 as setDefaultLimit in _construct() function.

Comment: Sure,

Add something like this in you class:
````
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setDefaultLimit(100);
        if ($this->hasData('default_filter')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter($this->getData('default_filter'));
        }
    }

Comment: why we do a test for the data 'default_filter'

Comment: The code I posted was a fragment of a module that sets some default filters (for this specific project) in another function (_prepareColumns). It looks like this:

$filters = [
            'status' => 1,
            'attribute_set_id' => 4,
            'visibility' => 4,
            'type_id' => 'simple'
        ];

        $this->_setFilterValues($filters);

Comment: the preference is not working bro , can you help me i have addd a di file , and put in this ==> class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product {

  public function _construct() {

    parent::_construct();
    $this->setDefaultLimit(100);
  }

}    and i can't override the main class of magento ,

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope that makes things clear.

Comment: yes this is the same what i have done, but it's not working, the debugger doesn't enter into my class even if i have done all correctly , did you test it on you machine ?

Comment: And you've created a module?
Is it present in app/etc/config.php? Is it enabled?
Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: yes i have already the module catalog enabled , i have many overrides on it , so i think this is not the problem at all

Comment: Good news !! -> i have found the solution we should override this class Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Merchandiser\Grid  it extends from   \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product